# "Estimated effects may be unbalanced" R error message

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am getting the error message: "Estimated effects may be unbalanced
8 observations deleted due to missingness"

**data table**

[image: 1]

```
setwd("/Users/jacksmir/Documents/R format data")
CMTT_nano <- read.csv("CMTT_nano_NOM.csv")

CMTT_nano$conc <- as.factor(CMTT_nano$conc)

# Perform one-way ANOVA
model <- aov(hatch ~ conc, data = CMTT_nano)

# Obtain ANOVA results
anova_result <- summary(model)
```

I was trying to compare concentration and hatch rate but the anova doesn't produce a p-value and I don't know why

Comment: Can we please have a [mcve]?  It's hard to tell exactly what's going on here otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for posting the data. One more request: could you please post it in a *text* form (i.e., the output of `dput(CMTT_nano)` **or** cut-and-pasting the text of the table into a code-formatted block (delimited with ``` ) ?